# How can i have references without number?

Tags: citing

My references in my article shouldn't have numbers, but must be like
CHILD, B. and VENUGOPAL, V. 2010 Optimal configurations of wave energy device arrays.Ocean Engineering 37, 1402-1417.
How can I disable numbering in references section? 
I used:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ref1}
.
.
.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Change the citing or bibliography style ... depends on the packages being used

Comment: You should have a look at automated tools like `biblatex`/`biber` instead of doing stuff by hand. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The number as reference is one the possibility (and a default one).

If you use `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` you will have: `[foo99]` for exemple.

You can have more style will looking at http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm